# NodeJS Express REST API get request returns empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I am trying to build REST API with NodeJS and Express. I create routes for `offers` and when I try to send GET request I get empty response with 200 status code

routes.js

```
  router.get('', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: true}), OfferController.getOffers);
```

offerController.js

```
  exports.getOffers = function(req, res) {
    Offer.find({}, function(err, task) {
      if (err){
        return res.send(err);
      }
      res.json(Offer);
    });
  }
```

what is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
exports.getOffers = function(req, res) {
    Offer.find({}, function(err, task) {
      if (err){
        return res.send(err);
      }
      // Change this line from res.json(Offer) to:
      res.json(task);
    });
  }
```

The result of `Offer.find()` is in task variable, that's what you want to send back to client.

Comment: Can you explain what you changed? Explaining the why's turns a right answer into a great answer

Comment: @SterlingArcher You're right, I have explained my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`Offer` is a mongoose model you can not send it back. And you don't need to return it because it is async.

Use this structure:

```
exports.getOffers = function(req, res) {
    Offer.find({}, function(error, result) {
        var myRes = {};
        if(error){
            myRes.error = error;
            myRes.error.message = "Error..."
        }else{
            myRes.data = result;
        }
        res.send(myRes);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you sending `Offer`?

You should be sending the output of `Offer.find({})` i.e. `task`.

So, `res.send(task)` should be the statement after your error condition. It would look something like:

```
exports.getOffers = function(req, res) {
  Offer.find({}, function(err, task) {
    if (err){
      return res.send(err);
    }

    res.json(task); //this
});
```